# Autopilot white glove deployment install applications

Tags: deployment

Right now we have multiple applications in Intune and when we enroll a computer the applications get installed depending on what group the user is a part of. So we want to implement the white glove deployment. Since with the white glove deployment the user doesnt have to login first how can we make sure that they get the right applications?